# Alternatives for "sit with someone"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> "Do not think you know me if at school you took a picture with me."
>
> "Do not think you know me if at college you are *sitting with me*."

These two lines are meant to rhyme, but they don't sound natural to me. The second one just sounds completely off. Are there any alternatives for **sitting with someone** that would fit in it's place? Also, if you could suggest some changes in the first line, I would be thankful.

Comment: "Seated beside me"?

Comment: What is the problem you have with *sitting with me* - is it the word *sitting* or *with* or the whole thing?

Comment: @Smock this is what I want to say: "_Do not think you know me if you sit with me at college everyday_". So does _"Do not think you know me if at college you are **sitting with me**"_ work? Is there any grammatical error? I feel like there might be.

Comment: @BellaSwan but it has to rhyme with the first sentence.

Comment: @Smock If it sounds okay, then I'll go with it.

Comment: @Rhythm the second sentence sounds okay to me

Comment: @BellaSwan oh thanks, how bout the first one?

Comment: In terms of parallel style, the tenses should probably match. In other words, use either *you **are taking** a picture with me* along with the existing second line or *you **sat** with me* along with the existing first line. Following the past tense with the present tense seems odd to me.

Comment: I think you should put that as an Answer @JasonBassford as I think that's the only thing I see as being odd about these two lines